# Is it possible to make OpenStack work with MaaS without involving Juju?

Tags: juju, kvm-virtualization, maas, openstack

I have to machines, `{machine-A: will be used as my Master MAAS server with OpenStack}` and `{machine-B [Quad Core/16GB RAM/8x HDD]: will be running a KVM where all my nodes will run on}`

## Purpose

I want to create 7 nodes on the KVM server by using my MaaS server. Then install OpenStack on the MaaS server and then use OpenStack to create instances of Ubuntu 12.04 images on each node.

**NOTE:** There are so many questions on this community threads which are helpful but none seem to be able to explain or phrase the question of how OpenStack connect to MaaS nodes.

## Questions

1. How will I be able to use OpenStack to create Linux instance on each node without the help of Juju? (I don't seem to understand that part a little in the Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with OpenStack.)
2. Do I really need Juju to help OpenStack connect with my Maas Nodes? if so, see next question -
3. After Juju bootstrap is created and nodes start up under Juju status, does OpenStack automatically sees the nodes with the help of Juju or you have to make some changes in some config files?
4. Should I not use my KVM server as a KVM server and just add it as a node to MaaS and use OpenStack to allocate hard disk volume size I want for an instance? Without using KVM.

I will really appreciate helpful responses and if possible, kb articles that explain how this can be done.

Comment: Since I haven't received any questions, I've been doing some itensive research and reading. One question I will like to be answered is:
If I install MaaS on one whole server, and KVM on the second server, will I have to install OpenStack on the server with the KVM and then use Nova to help create Volumes and Instances?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I'm good now after spending a whole week reading and practicing, I fully understand the relationships between OpenStack, Juju and MaaS as well as Kernel Virtualization. I'm able to deploy a working OpenStack on a dedicated hardware and VMs (KVM/QEMU).

However, I wouldn't mind anyone posting more interesting articles on MaaS and Juju Magical powers.

Note: I will post a new question about VirtualBox and MaaS in another thread.

Comment: could you elaborate on each of your specific questions?